# Why rounded corners when changing a Win32 window's parent?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, visual-c++, parent

I'm trying to learn how to make a top-level Win32 window become a child of another window.

When I change a window's parent, I still get ugly rounded corners, as though it was a top-level window with a rounded title bar. Why? And how do I fix this? (I couldn't get `WM_UPDATEUISTATE` to help, but I'm not sure how to use it correctly either.)

[image: Screenshot]

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
int _tmain()
{
    WNDCLASS wndClass = {
        0, &DefWindowProc, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW),
        GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_3DFACE), NULL, TEXT("MyWindowClass")
    };
    ATOM atom = RegisterClass(&wndClass);
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(MAKEINTATOM(atom), TEXT("Win"),
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    HWND hWndChild = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        WC_EDIT, TEXT("Control"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
        10, 10, 86, 24, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    SetParent(hWndChild, hWnd);                     // Change the parent
    SetWindowLong(hWndChild, GWL_STYLE,             // Set child styles
        GetWindowLong(hWndChild, GWL_STYLE)
            & ~(WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU |
                WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX)
            | WS_CHILDWINDOW);
    SetWindowPos(hWndChild, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0,       // Refresh
        SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE
            | SWP_NOOWNERZORDER | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
    BOOL bRet;
    MSG msg;
    while ((bRet = GetMessage(&msg, hWnd, 0, 0)) != 0 && bRet != -1)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: A child window should be WS_CHILD and not WS_POP.

Comment: @HansPassant: Right, that's why I used `SetWindowLong` to change the styles after creation. Or did I miss something?

Comment: This is highly irregular. Better would be to create the window as a child from the beginning -- initially put it inside a top-level window parent. Then you can move it to a new parent without having to fiddle with all the styles.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Right, but the question is, how do you do this when the window *isn't* a child at the beginning? I don't really mind if the code is complicated, as long as it works. (Is it even possible? I thought the existence of `SetParent` implies that it is...)

Comment: @RaymondChen: Or, let me pose a different question, if you will: Which properties of a window should *not* be modified after the window is created? (In other words, which parameters to `CreateWindowEx` can I put off until later, and which parameters must I supply *right there* for correct operation?) From your response, I'm assuming `hwndParent` is one of them, and (obviously) the class name is one of them -- but are there any others?

Comment: Parent and owner are risky things to change after creation, since so many pieces of code do things like walk the parent or owner chain, and if you change the chain at runtime, things can get wonky.

Comment: @RaymondChen: I understand it's *risky* (native Win32 programming is always risky :P), but is it *possible* to do this, if your code is correct?

Comment: Yes, you can do it in principle, but getting it correct is very hard and not even I know completely what the correct steps are.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Ah okay, I see. If you post that as an answer I'll definitely accept it then, thanks. :)

Comment: It's not really an answer. You can.post your own answer and accept it.

Comment: Some window styles are only adhered to on window creation. Others are used during operation. Which depends entirely on the control and the authors. If their documentation says it can be changed after creation then it can be. If they don't, you can't guarantee that it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this is possible in principle but difficult to get 'right' practically (according to Raymond's comment).

I found that `SetWindowRgn(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);` does the trick, but I don't think it's correct -- there might be other things I've missed. So the correct solution is probably to just construct the object correctly at the beginning.