# Control not being redrawn properly after changing parent

Tags: c, winapi, win32gui

A possible similar (but also not similar) [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472129/why-rounded-corners-when-changing-a-win32-windows-parent).

I'm trying to create popout windows (like the dockable panes in Visual Studio). I have a window initially created with:

```
CreateWindowEx(NULL, classname, caption, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | extrastyles, 5, 30, 300, 300, hParent, NULL, hInst, NULL);
```

Which contains an edit control:

```
HWND edittmp = NULL; //Temporary global variable.
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        CREATESTRUCT* cs = (CREATESTRUCT*)(lParam);
        if (!edittmp)
            edittmp = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, L"EDIT", L"edit control", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | ES_MULTILINE | WS_VSCROLL, 0, 0, 20, 100, hwnd, (HMENU)IDC_EDIT1, cs->hInstance, 0);
        else
            SetParent(edittmp, hwnd); //Transfer the controls to the recreated parent window.
        break;
    }
```

In order to pop the window out I `PostMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);` and then recreate the window with `WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_POPUP` since I understand that for `WM_POPUP` the window must be recreated.

My approach of not destroying the controls and simply changing their parent is so that there need not be any manual attempt to preserve the data contained within each control (in this case the text contained within the edit control). However it seems that the edit control isn't being drawn correctly after changing parents:

[image: Drawing trouble]

What could be going wrong here?

Comment: I am sorry that I cannot construct a sample that can reproduce the problem based on your description.Could you please show [a minimal, reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) without private information?

Comment: The edit control is sending messages to the original parent, which you destroyed. What you can do is wrap the edit control inside another window that is itself reparented.

Comment: Would that not shift the problem over to the wrapper window? Is it possible to reconfigure the child window to send messages to the new parent?

Comment: You just need to make sure that the parent window of the editing window will not be destroyed.

Comment: After doing some investigation into the MFC templates from VS, it would appear that MFC does use the wrapper window (in the form of an `Afx:ControlBar`). I've adopted this tactic and it seems to be working ok! Thanks.